# Strange NPE behavior while working with ArrayLists

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, integer

I have 3 `public static ArrayList<Integer>` arrayLists named `hp,att & def` respectively on a class called `GlobalDataHolder.java`. When i try to add an Integer value to those `ArrayLists` from within a method called `addSelectedCardToGlobalUserBox` from another class with the name `MainScreenFragment.java`, i get a **`NPE`** that states that the hp `ArrayList` is null thus preventing me from adding values to it. The strange thing is that this exception only happens when i run the app on a physical device and not on an emulator. Any ideas?

ArrayLists:

```
    // Holds each card's hp stats
public static ArrayList<Integer> hp = new ArrayList<>();

// Holds each card's att stats
public static ArrayList<Integer> att = new ArrayList<>();

// Holds each card's def stats
public static ArrayList<Integer> def = new ArrayList<>();
```

addSelectedCardToGlobalUserBox() method:

```
    /**
 * Add the selected card's icon to the Global User Box
 * @param position Holds the selected card's position.
 * This is used to define where the icon should be placed in the grid &
 * which icon from the DataBase was selected
 */
private void addSelectedCardToGlobalUserBox(int position) {
    GlobalDataHolder.dataHolder.add(ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.cardArts.add(CardInfoDatabase.cardArts[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.cardNameAndDescription.add(CardInfoDatabase.cardNameAndDescription[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.leaderSkills.add(CardInfoDatabase.leaderSkills[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.superAttacksName.add(CardInfoDatabase.superAttacksName[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.superAttacksDesc.add(CardInfoDatabase.superAttacksDesc[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.passiveSkillsName.add(CardInfoDatabase.passiveSkillsName[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.passiveSkillsDesc.add(CardInfoDatabase.passiveSkillsDesc[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.hp.add(CardInfoDatabase.hp[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.att.add(CardInfoDatabase.att[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.def.add(CardInfoDatabase.def[position]);
}
```

MainScrenFragment.java class for reference:

```
public class MainScreenFragment extends Fragment {

// Main Grid View
GridView gridView;

public MainScreenFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_screen, container, false);

    gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridViewLayout);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getContext())); // used to set the contents of the GridView-in this case images-
    registerForContextMenu(gridView);

    // When an item from the GridView gets clicked
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Create a new Intent...
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),CardViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Card Index",position);
            intent.putExtra("GLB_CARD_INDEX", -1);
            intent.putExtra("SCREEN_WIDTH",1080);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

// Create a Context Menu when an item in the GridView is long-pressed
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Card Options");
    //AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo cmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    menu.add(1,v.getId(),0, "Add Card to GLB");
    menu.add(2,v.getId(),0,"Add Card to JP");
}

// When an item in the context menu gets selected, call a method
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Get some extra info about the contextMenu
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    int position = info.position; // clicked view's position

    if(item.getTitle().equals("Add Card to GLB")) {
        addCardMessage("Card added to GLB");
        addSelectedCardToGlobalUserBox(position);
    } else if (item.getTitle().equals("Add Card to JP")) {
        addCardMessage("Card added to JP");
        addSelectedCardToJPUserBox(position);
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Creates a snackbar message, telling the user which card was added to which box
 * @param text Defines into which User Box the card was added
 */
private void addCardMessage( String text) {
      final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(gridView, text ,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

      snackbar.setAction("Dismiss", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            snackbar.dismiss();
        }
    });
    snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    snackbar.show();
}

/**
 * Add the selected card's icon to the Global User Box
 * @param position Holds the selected card's position.
 * This is used to define where the icon should be placed in the grid &
 * which icon from the DataBase was selected
 */
private void addSelectedCardToGlobalUserBox(int position) {
    GlobalDataHolder.dataHolder.add(ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.cardArts.add(CardInfoDatabase.cardArts[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.cardNameAndDescription.add(CardInfoDatabase.cardNameAndDescription[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.leaderSkills.add(CardInfoDatabase.leaderSkills[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.superAttacksName.add(CardInfoDatabase.superAttacksName[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.superAttacksDesc.add(CardInfoDatabase.superAttacksDesc[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.passiveSkillsName.add(CardInfoDatabase.passiveSkillsName[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.passiveSkillsDesc.add(CardInfoDatabase.passiveSkillsDesc[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.hp.add(CardInfoDatabase.hp[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.att.add(CardInfoDatabase.att[position]);
    GlobalDataHolder.def.add(CardInfoDatabase.def[position]);
}

/**
 * Add the selected card's icon to the JP User Box
 * @param position Holds the selected card's position.
 * This is used to define where the icon should be placed in the grid &
 * which icon from the DataBase was selected
 */
private void addSelectedCardToJPUserBox(int position) {
    JPDataHolder.dataHolder.add(ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    JPDataHolder.cardArts.add(CardInfoDatabase.cardArts[position]);
    JPDataHolder.cardNameAndDescription.add(CardInfoDatabase.cardNameAndDescription[position]);
    JPDataHolder.leaderSkills.add(CardInfoDatabase.leaderSkills[position]);
    JPDataHolder.superAttacksName.add(CardInfoDatabase.superAttacksName[position]);
    JPDataHolder.superAttacksDesc.add(CardInfoDatabase.superAttacksDesc[position]);
    JPDataHolder.passiveSkillsName.add(CardInfoDatabase.passiveSkillsName[position]);
    JPDataHolder.passiveSkillsDesc.add(CardInfoDatabase.passiveSkillsDesc[position]);
    JPDataHolder.hp.add(CardInfoDatabase.hp[position]);
    JPDataHolder.att.add(CardInfoDatabase.att[position]);
    JPDataHolder.def.add(CardInfoDatabase.def[position]);
}

}
```

NPE:

> 01-01 16:05:51.421 22357-22357/com.dcv.spdesigns.dokkancards E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.dcv.spdesigns.dokkancards, PID: 22357
>                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                      at com.dcv.spdesigns.dokkancards.ui.MainScreenFragment.addSelectedCardToGlobalUserBox(MainScreenFragment.java:122)
>                                                                                      at com.dcv.spdesigns.dokkancards.ui.MainScreenFragment.onContextItemSelected(MainScreenFragment.java:79)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performContextItemSelected(Fragment.java:2502)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchContextItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:3319)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchContextItemSelected(FragmentController.java:357)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:377)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:108)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:108)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$PhoneWindowMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:4020)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:157)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:339)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1718)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:4184)
>                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView$13.run(AbsListView.java:6754)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you must be assigning those variables `null`. Try making the variable `final` and check where the `null` is being assigned (The compilation failure will indicate where you are assigning null).